# What are the potential arguments passable to Ember.run()

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've come across something like this a few time:

`Enber.run(null, resolve, results);`

On [Ember's Documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html) for `Ember.run()` they only have `Ember.run(function() {})`.

The actual [`ember.js`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.4.0/packages/ember-metal/lib/run_loop.js#L28) file isnt too much different.

What are the possible arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the link under "DEFINED IN:" [ember.js line 28](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.4.0/packages/ember-metal/lib/run_loop.js#L28) you can see that it's awaiting **three** parameter, namely `target` and `method` and `args*`

`args` is referred to here:

> Any additional arguments you wish to pass to the method

Also, I would suggest to use already existing functions of `Ember.run` if you can solve your specific problem with them.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha. Thanks. I think I saw that but the format of defining it escaped me. I'm used to seeing things defined like, `Ember.run({target}, function, [args])`. Or something close